# How to configure dyanmic weaving for eclipselink

Tags: jpa-2.0, eclipselink

When I run JPA JUnit cases for a given set of Entities. The very first test case is failing and rest other are successful.

I am using JPA2.0 with Eclipselink2.3.2 and spring3.0. Currently i configured weaving as static

```
<property name="jpaPropertyMap">
    <map>
    <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"></entry>
    </map>
</property>
```

This is disabling the lazy-loading feature and loading all the entities as eager.
Can anyone let us know how to configure weaving.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear if you like to know how to configure weaving in general or how dynamic weaving is configured (as your topic intends).

Answer (score 1):

Your title asks about dynamic weaving, so I am not sure why you would use a property stating you have already statically woven your classes.  Static weaving means you have already changed the byte codes in the classfiles by running the static weaver on them.
This is described at
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_(ELUG)#Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Weaving

Dynamic weaving outside of a container requires using an agent specified at startup:
-javaagent:eclipselink.jar

You may have trouble with spring - this question was already asked and answered here:
[How do I configure dynamic weaving using EclipseLink & Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417863/how-do-i-configure-dynamic-weaving-using-eclipselink-spring)