# Lazy setting are being reverted by EclipseLink on runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, eclipselink

I have a springboot app(java11, spring5.3.23, eclipselink2.6.7) which on runtime reverts lazy setting on all ManyToOne associations.

> Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute

My **persistence.xml** has following properties:

```
<property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="true"/>
<property name="eclipselink.weaving.internal" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.weaving.fetchgroups" value="false"/>
```

Also, I have this configuration(simplified version below), which on runtime sets weaving to true

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("oracle")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
public class PersistenceConfig
{
    @Bean
    public PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager(
        @Qualifier("temp") DataSource dataSource, 
        LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver)
    {
        DefaultPersistenceUnitManager manager = new DefaultPersistenceUnitManager();
        manager.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        manager.setDefaultPersistenceUnitName("com.model.data");
        manager.setDefaultDataSource(dataSource);
        manager.setLoadTimeWeaver(loadTimeWeaver);
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder(JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter, 
        PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager) {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(jpaVendorAdapter, getVendorProperties(), persistenceUnitManager);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
            @Qualifier("temp") DataSource dataSource,
            PersistenceUnitManager persistenceUnitManager) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.model.data" });
        factory.setPersistenceUnitManager(persistenceUnitManager);
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factory.setJpaProperties(getProperties());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.ORACLE);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("oracle");
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        return adapter;
    }

    protected Properties getProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.putAll(getVendorProperties());
        return properties;
    }

    protected  Map<String, Object> getVendorProperties()
    {
        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING, "true");
        map.put(PersistenceUnitProperties.WEAVING_INTERNAL, "false");

        return map;
    }
```

I have tried following this article to implement dynamic weaving since I only have few classes that are required to be weaved.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Dynamic_Weaving

Using following command to run my application(with eclipseLink jar as javaagent):

> java -javaagent:C:\Users\suyash.yadav.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\5.3.23\spring-instrument-5.3.23.jar -javaagent:C:\Users\suyash.yadav.m2\repository\org\eclipse\persistence\eclipselink\2.6.7\eclipselink-2.6.7.jar -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4004 -jar target\my-app-name-web-1.2.3-exec.war

But I'm getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo
>
> FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Any suggestions on what else I can try here?

Comment: You shouldn't have needed to put in the agent - spring should do that for you. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-eclipselink and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6425337/496099 , the later of which states you need to be sure you do not access the classes within the persistence unit before accessing the Spring context or they will be loaded without weaving.